# /etc/login.defs: ENV_PATH & ENV_SUPATH vs PATH

Tags: environment-variables, login, path

In `/etc/login.defs` what are `ENV_PATH` and `ENV_SUPATH` used for?

From `/etc/login.defs`:

```
 # REQUIRED  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.  
 #  
 # (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)  
 ENV_SUPATH   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  
 ENV_PATH     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

- They seem to default to the same exact initial path values that I have for `PATH` in `/etc/profile` in Debian Jessie.
- In man it says very briefly what **login.defs** is used for. [This](http://linuxsuperuser07.blogspot.com/2012/05/understanding-etclogindefs.html) page says a bit more.

`PATH` and `ENV_PATH` don't appear to be connected or dependent on one another, or if they are it's not obvious to me how one depends on the other.

**Do I need to update my bash system paths in both of these two places?** Or is there a way to have paths defined in only one place, and to refer to this master path value?

Or perhaps are these just used as a default in the case that `PATH` is missing?  ... So they don't really matter that much ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the man page about [login.defs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html)

> ENV_PATH (string)
>              If set, it will be used to define the PATH environment variable
>              when a regular user login. The value is a colon separated list of
>              paths (for example /bin:/usr/bin) and can be preceded by PATH=.
>              The default value is PATH=/bin:/usr/bin.
>
> ENV_SUPATH (string)
>              If set, it will be used to define the PATH environment variable
>              when the superuser login. The value is a colon separated list of
>              paths (for example /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin) and can be
>              preceded by PATH=. The default value is
>              PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin.

Both are used to define the PATH variable of regular, super user initially.
My login.defs has the ENV_PATH, ENV_SUPATH defined to following

```
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I added a new user 'foo'

```
sudo useradd foo

sudo passwd foo                                                                                                     
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

When i login as 'foo'

```
foo@naga-playground:/$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Similarly for 'root'

```
root@naga-playground:/home/pi/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The PATH can be overridden by the user via .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc ...

To make the answer complete
ENV_PATH is used to define PATH for a regular user
ENV_SUPATH is used to define PATH for a super user

Comment: Thanks.  So is it a temporary initial value for a newly created user's PATH, which can then later be overwritten by ~/.bashrc or the like once that is setup?

Comment: Yes, it is the initial value of PATH environment variable